# Undercurrent E-stop

Tags: current, safety, maximum-ratings

what would be the effects of an emergency stop button rated significantly lower than the system's current draw?

Say for example, an e-stop rated for 10A DC in a system pulling 20A DC. Would the e-stop still function as designed to?

Comment: It all depends on how it is wired and whether relays are used so, you need to provide a schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this.

The contacts could weld together, defeating the emergency stop functionality.  The switch would probably overheat somewhere (remember that doubling the current quadruples resistive heating), which could at worst cause a fire or could cause the switch to fail in a less-spectacular way. I imagine liability issues in the result of an accident would fall squarely on your shoulders. Use the switch to control a relay; they're cheap.

Comment: So, it is preferred that it be an e-stop for the sake of complexity. As i am part of a club and we do competitions. The competitions rule states we need a red button on our robot to function as an e-stop. So an e-stop is perfect for this, but i have considered using a relay which is controlled by a simple red button. As the only requirement is that it be a red button with at least some particular size that functions as an e-stop; Of course there is more to this rule but these are the relevant points.

Comment: perhaps you can replace the microswiches in the estop button with ones that can handle more current.